# Limit appended items to x number

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project and seem to have hit a wall. What I'm trying to achieve is when a button is clicked, a div with the class="testing" should be appended to a div. However I want these to be limited to 5 times only, so that if there are 5 divs with the class="testing", instead of appending an alert is shown.

This is what I have:

```
$('#campaign_builder_new').click(function() {
    var question_row = $('div').hasClass('testing')
    if ($(question_row).length > 5) { 
        alert('no more');
    }

    else { 
        $('#campaign_builder_questions_area').append('<div class="testing">hi</div>')
    }

    });
```

However it keeps going after the item number 5... Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `question_row` variable is a bit off:

```
var question_row = $('#campaign_builder_questions_area .testing');
```

`question_row` is now an array of your appended classes - checking the `.length` of `question_row` should work now.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you soooooo much! It says I have to wait 10 mins before I mark this answer as good. Will do as soon as it lets me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("div .testing").length > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`hasClass` doesn't filter your result set it simply returns true or false.
What you're thinking of is `.filter`

```
$('div').filter('.testing')
```

but a single selector can be used insted

```
$('div.testing')
```